# typescript classes: Unexpected reserved word 'private'

Tags: typescript, class

I previously used these classes in another project, but now when I moved them to this project, I get the following errors: **'Unexpected reserved word 'private'**.

[image]

I didn't change anything in the classes, I just took the files and put them in another project. Does anyone know what causes this?

This is an example of one of my service classes:

```
class FetchService {
  constructor(private baseUrl: string, private authService?: AuthService) {}

  post(endpoint: string, options?: Options) {
    return this.request(endpoint, { ...options, method: 'POST' });
  }

  put(endpoint: string, options?: Options) {
    return this.request(endpoint, { ...options, method: 'PUT' });
  }

  get(endpoint: string, options?: Options) {
    return this.request(endpoint, options);
  }

  patch(endpoint: string, options?: Options) {
    return this.request(endpoint, { ...options, method: 'PATCH' });
  }

  private request(endpoint: string, options?: Options) {
    const requestInit = {
      ...this.options(options),
      headers: this.headers(options),
    };

    if (options?.body && !(options?.body instanceof FormData)) {
      requestInit.body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
    }

    if (this.authService != null && !options?.skipAuthentication) {
      const userToken = this.authService.getUserToken();
      if (userToken != null) {
        requestInit.headers.append(
          'Authorization',
          `Bearer ${userToken.accessToken}`,
        );
      }
    }

    return fetch(this.endpoint(endpoint), requestInit)
      .then(response => (response.ok ? response : Promise.reject(response)))
      .then(async res => {
        // when we receive the token, we should store it in our localstorage
        // TODO: try to find a more elegant solution for handling response headers
        // outside of this function
        let accessToken = res.headers?.get('authorization');
        if (accessToken) {
          // remove the 'bearer'
          // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
          accessToken = accessToken.split(' ')[1];
          localStorage.setItem(
            LocalStorageKey.USER_TOKEN,
            JSON.stringify({ accessToken }),
          );
        }

        const resAsText = await res.text();
        try {
          return JSON.parse(resAsText);
        } catch (e) {
          return Promise.resolve();
        }
      })
      .catch(async err => {
        const { status } = err;

        if (err instanceof Error) {
          return Promise.reject({
            title: err.message,
          });
        }

        const apiError = await this.parseErrorResponse(err, endpoint);

        if (status === 401) {
          this.authService?.clearUserToken();
          return Promise.reject({
            ...apiError,
            title: 'Unauthorized',
          });
        }

        if (status === 403) {
          this.authService?.clearUserToken();
          return Promise.reject({
            ...apiError,
            title: 'Forbidden',
          });
        }

        if (status === 404) {
          return Promise.reject({
            ...apiError,
            title: 'Not found',
          });
        }

        return Promise.reject(apiError);
      });
  }

  private async parseErrorResponse(
    err: any,
    endpoint: string,
  ): Promise<ApiError> {
    const txt = await err.text();
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(txt);
      return {
        title:
          json.error ?? json.title ?? json.message ?? 'Something went wrong',
        description: json.error_description ?? json.detail ?? '',
        fields: json.errors ?? {},
        endpoint,
      };
    } catch {
      return {
        title: 'Something went wrong',
        description: '',
        endpoint,
      };
    }
  }

  private endpoint(endpoint: string) {
    return `${this.baseUrl}/${endpoint}`;
  }

  private options(options?: Options) {
    const defaultOptions: RequestInit = {
      method: 'GET',
    };
    return {
      ...defaultOptions,
      ...options,
    };
  }

  private headers(options?: Options) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    if (options?.headers) {
      Object.entries(options.headers).forEach(([key, header]) => {
        if (!header) {
          headers.delete(key);
        } else {
          headers.set(key, header);
        }
      });
    }

    return headers;
  }
}
```

extra info: this is the Approviders component where I initialize these services.

```
import React from "react";

import { MuiThemeProvider as ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { myfaro } from "@myfaro/themes-mui";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";

import { AppContextProvider } from "../core/context";
import { FetchProvider, FetchService } from "../core/api";
import { AuthProvider, AuthService } from "../core/auth";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const authService = new AuthService();
const fetchService = new FetchService(
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT ?? "",
  authService
);
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const AppProviders: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={myfaro}>
        <FetchProvider fetchService={fetchService}>
          <AuthProvider authService={authService}>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
              {children}
            </QueryClientProvider>
          </AuthProvider>
        </FetchProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
};

export default AppProviders;
```

Comment: What's the TypeScript version in each project?

Comment: 4.3.4 in the working project and 4.3.5 in the project that throws the errors.